# Find published npm modules using my npm module

Tags: javascript, github, npm

I've published *my* npm module to the default npm registry [1].
I've noticed many downloads, which of course makes me proud to be part of the open source community.

Is there a way to figure out which *other* published npm modules use *my* npm module as dependency?

[1] https://registry.npmjs.org

Comment: Did you look in the "Dependents" tab for your package? See e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/browse/depended/react. GitHub can do it on a repo basis too, if your code is hosted there; see Insights -> Dependency graph -> Dependents e.g. https://github.com/facebook/react/network/dependents.

Comment: Thank you @jonrsharpe. Exactly what I've been looking for.